# boost::asio is it wrong to rely on boost::asio::error::eof to detect end of response?

Tags: c++, node.js, boost, boost-asio

I have a Node.JS server which gets a query from a C++ app (built using boost::asio) and responds with a JSON.

1. The bytes transferred `boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred` does not match the `Content-Length`
2. Manually counting the body's size does match `Content-Length`
3. I can detect through `boost::asio::error::eof` when all data has arrived

The Node.JS server:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var reply = '{"payload":"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"}';

var app = function (req, res) {
    var bytes = Buffer.byteLength(reply, 'utf8');
    console.log("reply length: " + bytes);
    // non-chunked response
    res.writeHead(200, 
                  {"Content-Type" : "application/json",
                   "Content-Length" : bytes });
    res.end(reply);
}
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(9001);
server.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
});
```

I expect the response to contain `Content-Length` but other implementations using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` do not contain it.

If I rely solely on receiving `Content-Length` I can't detect when the server response is complete.

On the other hand, if I rely on detecting an `eof` I know that the server has finished responding.

```
void handle_read_content(const boost::system::error_code & err, std::size_t bytes)
{
    assert(socket_);
    if (!err)
    {
        boost::asio::async_read(*socket_.get(),
                                response_,
                                boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                                boost::bind(&asio_service_http::handle_read_content, 
                                            this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        std::string buffer((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&response_)), 
                            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

        std::call_once(cflag_, [&]{content_length(buffer, content_length_);
                                   std::string tmp = buffer;
                                   buffer = strip_header(tmp);});

        if (!buffer.empty()) {
            json_ += buffer;
            bytes_transferred_ += buffer.size();
        }
    }
    else if (err != boost::asio::error::eof) {
        error_handler(err);
    }
    else if (err == boost::asio::error::eof) {
        std::cout << "Buffer => \r\n" << json_ << std::endl;
    }
}
```

## Is this bad practice?

My guess is it doesn't guarantee that I've received the response, and only that server closed the connection ?

On the other hand, trying to match received bytes with content length:

```
if (!buffer.empty()) {
    json_ += buffer;
    bytes_transferred_ += buffer.size();
    if (bytes_transferred_ == content_length_){
        std::cout << "Buffer => \r\n" << json_ << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Only works with the header set properly.
For example, removing from the Node.JS server the content length:

```
var app = function (req, res) {
    var bytes = Buffer.byteLength(reply, 'utf8');
    console.log("reply length: " + bytes);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(reply);
}
```

Simply hangs. I know that the "correct way" would be to deal with both styles of response.
I can also detect if a `Content-Length` is set, and if not treat it as malformed response.

Comment: `(bytes_transferred_ == content_length_)` -- Terminating condition using `==` rather than `>=` is asking for trouble. For [chunked coding](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6) you need to parse the chunks and detect `last-chunk`. Connection-per-request is not most optimal for the server. It doesn't seem like a good idea to rely on the connection being closed only.

Comment: Reading HTTP messages correctly, i.e. to comply with [RFC7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) to RFC7235, isn't a simple task. I've had a go at it a version based on `boost asio` at [via-httplib](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib). You're welcome to use any of it that is useful to you.

Comment: @kenba thanks for the suggestion, unfortunatelly this is only a client and not a server.

Comment: @DanMašek Under what scenarios could that possibly happen (have more or equal bytes)? I'm not really concerned with chunked ATM, just wondering if its wrong to wait for the server to close the connection?

Comment: @Ælex In a universe where bugs don't exists it wouldn't happen, but ours doesn't seem to be the one. Or it could be malice. Like in for loops, I find it a good habit to write terminating conditions in this way. When you think about it -- you're supposed to get 200 bytes, but somehow you got 201 bytes. No matter how that transpired, it doesn't make sense to keep reading more -- you've already got all that you need, and more.

Comment: @Ælex As for waiting for connection being closed by the other side... It is a legitimate way to end the response, so you should definitely handle this scenario. However, there should also be some timeout mechanism to terminate the read in case the other side doesn't close the connection (for whatever reason, going over a network there are many things out of your control). The reason i mention chunked coding is that's when the `Content-Length` won't be there (even if it is, it should be ignored). If you send an HTTP 1.0 request, you won't receive chunked coding.

Comment: @DanMašek at some point I will work on chunked transfers, but for this version I'm mostly worried on making the Content-Length work. Thank you for your comments, feel free to answer if you want! :-D